# How to draw any plane 3D in irrlicht?

Tags: c++, irrlicht

I  have created a plane3D like this:

```
core::vector3df vec(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
core::vector3df vecnorm(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
core::plane3d<f32> plan= core::plane3df(vec,vecnorm);
```

but I can't find how to display it in a node?
Could you help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Irrlicht plane3d are not renderable.For drawing planes use createHillPlaneMesh from geometry creator

```
 SceneManager->getGeometryCreator()-> createHillPlaneMesh(....);
```